# addObserver method works only within the same class

Tags: ios, objective-c, observer-pattern

I would like to add an observer on the property of an object.

I use this method :

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"showButtons" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

When the observer and observed object is the same object the method `observeValueForKeyPath` i called, but when the observer is another object, the method is not called.

I explain what I have done.

I have an object `ViewManager` which has a property aString.

The class `AppContainer` has a property `ViewManager`.
In my class AppContainer, after the `ViewManager` property initilization, I add `AppContainer` as observer of ViewManager's aString property like this :

```
[self.viewManager addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"aString" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

In the `AppContainer` class, I have this method which is never called when the aString property changes.
Here is the never called method :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"has changed");
}
```

However I have added an observer in the `ViewManager` class itself like this :

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"aString" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and the called method in this class is :

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"itself");
}
```

when the observer and abserved object are the same, it works.

Could I have some help ?

Comment: Just after posting, I have found the origin of the problem. I added the observer in ViewDidLoad method instead of constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> In the AppContainer class, I have this method which is never called when the aString property changes.

Maybe it's because you call `self.viewManager addObserver` when it's `nil`?